# Winforms: TabControl-based Wizard with steps in separate classes and designer support

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wizard

I am trying to build a wizard by using the TabControl component.

It works fine, but I end up with so many pages (tabs) that having all the components and event handlers in one class makes it unreadable.

I now have this idea of declaring each step of the wizard in a separate class which extends from TabPage, then adding those steps to the wizard screen class (which extends from TabControl). How do I do that and still get designer support in the steps?

Simply extending TabPage doesn't enable designer support.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using UserControls that dock-fill your TabPages.  That moves a lot of the logic into separate classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest splitting your business logic from your UI logic.  Create `UserControl` derivatives for both the contents of each `TabPage` as well as the `TabControl` itself.  It's a lot easier to manage this kind of code if the UI logic is separate from the business logic.  You would probably benefit from creating a class for each tab, and a class that manages all the tabs.  Hook these classes up to the `UserControl`s that are on the `TabPage`s and the `TabControl`.